# Abstract harmonic analysis and cryptology

Tags: soft-question, algebraic-number-theory, cryptography

I am an undergraduate learning about abstract harmonic analysis (in the context of Tate’s thesis and algebraic number theory), and ideas relevant in modern cryptosystems (such as RSA, factoring). As I do not have a deep background in either topic, however, I was curious whether there are any connection between ideas/problems in modern cryptology (which seem to draw from algebraic number theory), and abstract harmonic analysis.

(I searched on Google but could not find anything)

Comment: Harmonic analysis plays an important role in modern lattice based cryptography. The big picture reason for this is fairly simple (though of course there's much more to it, and I'm not an expert): the Fourier transform is sort of the "right" tool for studying periodic things, and periodic things arise naturally on lattices.

Comment: On symmetric cryptography (private key crypto, stuff like AES or DES) there is relevant to study boolean functions, and there are a fourier transform for that functions, that is simply the fourier transform for finite cyclic groups in the case Z2.

Maybe you enjoy the book by Ryan O'Donell
https://arxiv.org/abs/2105.10386